# High performant and reliable database

Tags: mongodb, performance, elasticsearch, cassandra, database

I'm working on a project with a requirement of coming up with a huge amount of data.

For this we are looking for a data store to save and fetch a huge amount of data. The database is easy, there is one object for vouchers and a one to many relation to transactions. One voucher has ~ 10 - 100 transaction.
Sometimes it is possible that the system has to generate several thousand voucher in a short time, and it also possible that the system writes or delete several thousand transaction. 
And it is very important that the applications returns quickly if a voucher is valid or not (easy search request).

I have looked several blogs to find the best database for this and on the shortlist is

- MongoDB
- Elastic Search
- Cassandra

My favourite is Elastic Search but I found several blogs which says ES is not reliable enough to use as a primary data store. 
I also read some blogs that say mongodb has problems to run in cluster.
Do you have experience with Cassandra for a job like this? Or do you prefer any other database?

Comment: Define huge amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection of the database is the least concern in designing a huge database that needs high performance. Most Nosql and Relational databases can be made to run this type of application effectively. The hardware is critical, the actual design of your database and your indexing is critical, the types of queries you run need to be performant.

If I were to take on a project that required a very large database with high performance, the first and most critical thing to do is to hire a database expert who has worked with those types of systems for several years.   This is not something an application developer should EVER do. This is not the job for a beginner or even someone like me who has worked with only medium sized databases, albeit for over 20 years. You get what you pay for. In this case, you need to pay for real expertise at the design stage because database design mistakes are difficult to fix once they have data. Hire a contractor if you don't want a  permanent emplyee, but  hire expertise.

Answer (score 2):

I've some experience on MongoDB, but I'll go agnostic on this.

There are MANY factors that goes in game when you say that you want a fast  database. You have to think about indexing, vertical or horizontal scaling, relational or nosql, writing performance vs reading performance, and if you choose any of them should think about reading preferences, balancing, networking... The topics goes from the DB to the hardware.

I'd suggest go for a database you know, and that you can scale, admin and tune well.

In my personal experience, I've had no problems running MongoDB on cluster (sharding), may be problems comes due to a bad administration or planning, and that's why I suggest going for a database you know well.

Comment: I will add, evaluate good relational databases as well. They can go fast with huge (think terrabyte) datasets if they are properly designed.